# Extreme antonym for "standoffish"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Sites like thesaurus.com suggest "friendly", "sociable", and "warm" as antonyms, but those are the middle of the spectrum. I'm looking for a single word that goes beyond that, to describe someone that is *overly* "friendly", who takes liberties, who is unaware or slightly uninterested in other people's boundaries. Not in a clearly perverted or malevolent way. "Handsy" would be too strong and specific of a word (because it implies physical contact). "Oozing" would also be wrong - there may be little to no liquid. But you're having something like "ooze" foisted on you (any substance or practice that you don't want near you).

I search for this word every once in a while, with no success. This week I had to set up a Windows 10 computer. After opting out of Microsoft's invasive default settings, here I am again, trying to find a word that describes similar people (and companies). Sample sentence: "I try to avoid Windows 10, because it's the _____est software they've ever released (Clippy included)."

Comment: What's wrong with *unfriendly* or *aloof*? (The world needs more loofs...)

Comment: @Rob This is a request for an antonym, such as "overly friendly".

Comment: To the title question: He was ***all over him***, he was ***right in his face***...  To the body content: ***intrusive***, ***obnoxious***

Comment: I was thinking of 'gregarious' which goes being friendly to mean actually fond of company ... better antonym for standoffish.. but it's not a negative word (well perhaps to an aloof person has a natural disdain for gregarious types.)

Comment: @Jim Yeah! "All over him" is exactly the kind of thing I'm talking about. "Right in his face" has an element of deliberate menace though - that isn't quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few senses of [cloying](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cloying) that might fit:

> initially pleasurable or sweet but wearying in excess

and

> causing distaste or disgust through excess.

or

> overly ingratiating or sentimental.

although **most cloying** (not cloyingest) would have to fill in the blank.

Answer (score 1):

Forward, pushy, aggressive, assuming, audacious, bantam, impudent, nervy, overassertive, overweening, pert, presuming, presumptuous

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for exuberance?

(over)Exuberant

- :  joyously unrestrained and enthusiastic
- :  unrestrained or elaborate especially in
        style :  flamboyant

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that would apply more in some cases than others.

***glad-handing***

> [***glad-handing*** at Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/glad-handing)
>
> noun [ U ] UK ​ /ˈɡlædˌhænd.ɪŋ/ US ​ /ˈɡlædˌhænd.ɪŋ/ informal
>   ​
>
> - being very friendly to people you have not met before, as a way of trying to get an advantage:
>
> political glad-handing

or

> glad hand
>
> - an overly friendly welcome; a symbol of insincere attention. 
>     (*Typically: get ~; give someone ∼.)
>
> *Whenever I go into that store, I get the glad hand.*
>
> *I hate to go to a party and get the glad hand.*
>
> McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.
>
> glad hand
>
> - A warm and hearty but often insincere welcome or greeting, as in
>
> *Politicians are apt to give the glad hand to one and all.* [Slang; late 1800s]
>
> The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer. Copyright © 2003, 1997 by The Christine Ammer 1992 Trust. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.